# Location of DTD file on local machine, defined in DOCTYPE declaration, which gets referred while validating?

Tags: html, dtd

If we can validate the html page without internet connection, the DTD file must be somewhere on local machine.

Can someone tell me the location of the DTD file OR how the page can get validated without internet connection?

Comment: Who is the mysterious "we" in *"If we can validate"*?

Comment: And what are you using to validate your document?

Comment: Hi BoltClock - If you aware about the Dreamweaver, you may aware the validation process of HTML document..!

Comment: Hi Zeta, here "we" means I consider all the HTML programmers to whom I asked this query..!

Comment: @SachinG - Dreamweaver is most likely resolving the public identifier to a local instance of the DTD. I don't use Dreamweaver but you could do a search in the install directory or check Dreamweaver's help documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can the page be validated without an internet connection?  There are two obvious possibilities.

First, for any DTD, a special-purpose program can be constructed to validate documents against that DTD; since all the rules of the DTD are embodied by such a program, the DTD itself is not needed for such a program to run.

Second, any program may ship with a local copy of the DTD in question. The HTML DTDs are relatively stable, so it's not difficult to cache a local copy, and in fact [the W3C systems staff recommends that copies be cached locally](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/).

How can you find it?  On a Unix box, you might type `find / -name xhtml1-strict.dtd` or `find / -name html401.dtd`; on a Windows box, you'll have to identify and run a command with similar functionality.

Comment: Thank you for this information Sperberg-McQueen. Really appreciate.